# Why wont the component respond to the custom event?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am emitting an event called **emit-event-main2-counter** in  *Main2.vue*

Why will the data cntr in Bottom.vue not update?

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="app">
    <Main2 />
    <Bottom/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Main2 from "./components/Main2";
import Bottom from "./components/Bottom";

export default {
  components: {
    Main2,
    Bottom
  },

}
</script>

<style scoped>
  h1 {
    color: red;
  }
</style>
```

**Main2.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        main2 template <span class="text1">{{message}}</span>
        <button type="button" v-on:click="btnClickButton">my click</button>
        <div>{{counter}}</div>

    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import appInput from "./appInput.vue";
    export default {
        data: () => {
            return {
                message: "theText",
                counter: 0,
            }
        },
        components: {
           appInput,
       },
        methods: {
            btnClickButton(e) {
                this.$root.$emit('emit-event-main2-counter', this.counter)
                console.log('button');
                this.counter +=1;
            }
        }

    }
</script>

<style scoped>
.text1 {
    color:red;
}
.text2 {
    color:blue;
}
</style>
```

Bottom.vue

```
<template>
  <div  class="Bottom" v-on:emit-event-main2-counter="cntr = $event">
      bottom text and cntr ({{cntr}})
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    data: () => {
        return {
            cntr: 0
        }
    },
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Comment: in your case you should use event bus and use `this.$emit` instead of  `this.$root.$emit`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could emit an event to parent from `Main2` having as parameters `this.counter` and in the parent one receive that and pass it through `props` to `Bottom`

In `Main2` :

```
this.$emit("emit-event-main2-counter",this.counter);
```

in the `parent` component :

```
  <template>
   <Main2 v-on:emit-event-main2-counter="sendToBottom"/>
   <Bottom :cntr="pcounter"/>
  ....
  </template>


  data:{
   pcounter:0
    },
  methods:{
       sendToBottom(c){
        this.pcounter=c
          }
      }
```

`Bottom` should have property called `cntr`

```
  props:["cntr"]
```

Bottom.vue

```
     <template>
      <div  class="Bottom" >
          bottom text and cntr ({{cntr}})
      </div>
    </template>

  <script>

    export default {
           props:["cntr"],
         data: () => {
             return {
                }
            },
       }
     </script>
```

Comment: I give that solution according to your use case, because you have two components at the same level, in general case you should use event bus

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can an custom event only be passed up?

Comment: yes if you want to use like `v-on:cutomevent="handler"` else you should use `this.$on` to handle it somewhere else

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use root events, you need to emit the event with `this.$root.$emit()` and also listen to the event on the root like this: `this.$root.$on()`.

You should use it directly in the script part. Listen to the root event e.g. in the `created()` hook and then disable it with [`$off`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-root) in the `beforeDestroy()` hook.

---

However, I wouldn't encourage you to use `$root` events. It is usually better to communicate between the components like @BoussadjraBrahim proposed in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53351279/3233827).

If you have a more complex application, it makes sense to take a look at [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) and store the complete state in the Vuex store. By doing this, you can watch the global application state in the components and react if it changes. In this scenario, you would use the Vuex store instead of a root EventBus.

Comment: i proposed my solution according to this use case when having two components at the same level, the use event bus is for general use cases, try to enrich your answer with this [article](https://medium.com/@andrejsabrickis/https-medium-com-andrejsabrickis-create-simple-eventbus-to-communicate-between-vue-js-components-cdc11cd59860) +1